# Blazor WASM Hosted - Get UserId in both Client and API/Repository

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM Hosted solution that is broken out into a few projects.  Client is obviously the Client side WASM, Server is the server side which hosts the API Controller,  Data which is my data access that has the DataContext, Repositories, Migrations, ApplicationUser etc and then Models which is entirely just the models.  It is using Identity as its authentication/authorization

What I am looking to accomplish is 2 things

**1:**  I want to record the UserID on every save an update.

```
public async Task<Country> CreateAsync(Country country)
        {
            try
            {
                var addedEntity = _dataContext.Countries.Add(country);
                await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return addedEntity.Entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in CreateAsync()");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

In here id like to do country.CreatedBy = userId; (This is in the Data project)  How can I get the user information? In order to hit this section of code they have to be authorized.  Here is the Controller Action and that Controller is governed by the [Authorize] attribute

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Country country)
        {
            if (country == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                var createdCountry = await _repository.CreateAsync(country);
                return CreatedAtAction("GetById", new { id = createdCountry.Id }, createdCountry);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Create() - Returning Internal Server Error");
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

I would also like the have access to the userid at the controller level as well (this is in the server project).  I ultimately would like to add more logging and include the UserId in the log.

Here is my DataContext

```
public class DataContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options, IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        }
**db sets omitted**
}
```

2. In my Client project I want to have access to the UserId in the components for logging purposes as well.  Here is my App.razor which is using a CascadingAuthenticationState

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly"  AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(BBQFriend.Components.PageComponents.Index).Assembly }">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <Loading />
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h1>I think you're lost...</h1>
                        <div class="section-title-stripe"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

In my components i can

```
[Inject]
public AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
{
   var authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

}
```

The User is accessible from the AuthenticationState however I can only get the name from the authenticationState.User.Identity.Name but i want to get the UserId.  Can I add the UserId to the Identity or is there a way to get the UserId at the Client?  This is in the Client project so I do not have any of the Identity classes like UserManager or SigninManager here, those are on the Server.

***Update 1***
I have tried adding services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); to the Server Startup.cs ConfigureServices method and tried to use DI at the Repository level (in the Data project)

```
public IngredientRepository(DataContext dataContext, ILogger<IngredientRepository> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
            _logger = logger;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

            if(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;
            }           
        }
```

The Identity within this context however IsAuthenticated = True but contains no information regarding the user.  No claims, roles, name etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the UserId on the client by doing the following in the OnInitialize of a component.  I still need to figure out how to get the UserId and Name on the Server side at the level of the API Controller and Repository

```
var authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var user = authenticationState.User;

if(user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   userId = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;
   userName = user.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: Did you succeed in this?  I've just migrated a working .Net 5, out of the box MS Identity Wasm app to ,Net 6.  The new Blazor templates used Duende Identity Server (as opposed to basic MS Identity), so that was no good.  I had to use Chris Sainty's blog post to get it working,  But I also need to access the logged in use in the Wasm Controller & User.Identity never gives me an ID or email.  UserManager also doesn't get it.  From another post I added the following - no change: builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
opt.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier

Comment: i did not upgrade to .net6 because of the duende identity server upgrade which broke my entire site.

Answer (score 0):

Using Auth in the client is all well and good. However this should be used only to control visibility and access to client features.

To secure your API mark your API method or the whole controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute

```
[Authorize]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase 
{
    ...
```

Add a constructor to the controller

```
       
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public WeatherForecastController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {           
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
```

Then from within your controller method call this function:

```
private async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUser()
{
    ApplicationUser user = default;

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
              
        user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    }

    return user;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/BrianLParker/WebApiUserAccess) is a repo I made from the template.
For a complete example with roles and policies I have a repo [here](https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp)

Comment: Parts of what you said are relevant and some arent.  As i mentioned my application is a Blazor WASM Hosted solution with Identity.  So the Server project is a .netcore webapi that serves the Blazor WASM solution.  The Server project is where the WebAPI Controllers live.  This is out of the box installation from VS2019.  The application uses DefaultIdentity with EF and IdentityServer as the Authorization and Authentication.  What you proposed with Injecting the Usermanager in a controller and accessing the User in the controller does not work at the APIController because User is null.

Comment: @JoeyD Sorry Ill update my code. The repo I took this from is setup to pass the email as a claim. I will update my answer to work with a "out of the box" self hosted.

Comment: So in that instance I can see that the User has claims but within the claims there is not a NameIdentifier at all. User.Identity.Name is null.  So im assuming I need to add the .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>(); that you have in the AuthApp example

Comment: @JoeyD I did not have to do this in the new repo. I only made changes in the controller from the template. I placed a breakpoint in the controller and inspected the `User` property. It only took me a few minutes to make that repo. I did little changes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the userId and  thename from the controllers you need to use the HttpContext property of the controllers. The way that i like to do it is by creating extension methods:

```
public static string GetUserId(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User is null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    }

    public static string GetUserName(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User is null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
    }
```

Then you can call them inside your controllers:

```
 var userId = HttpContext.GetUserId();
 var userName = HttpContext.GetUserName();
```